# Whitespace with perl Switch module

Tags: perl

The following trivially short perl program works fine (and does nothing, as expected):

```
use Switch;
switch (1) {}
```

However if I put the program on one line, as follows,

```
use Switch; switch (1) {}
```

I get an error

```
richard@affric:~$ perl foo.pl
syntax error at foo.pl line 1, near ") {"
Execution of foo.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

(Edit: Yes, I know Switch.pm is deprecated, and, yes, I know that the code is more readable with the line break.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Switch`](https://metacpan.org/module/Switch) module is written as a [Perl filter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfilter.html), which essentially means that the `Switch` module gets to see and make changes to the source code before the perl parser gets it.

I believe what you're seeing here is just a bug in the filter. If you use the backend [`B::Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/module/B::Deparse) module then you get a chance to see what nasty things `Switch` has done to your program. For instance, for your initial version

```
perl -MO=Deparse myswitch.pl
```

produces

```
use Switch;

S_W_I_T_C_H: while (1) {
    local $_S_W_I_T_C_H;
    &Switch::switch(1);
}
continue {
    (last);
}
```

so you can see that there is plenty of scope for error.

If I had to guess I would say that `Switch` is simply expecting all of the line starting `use Switch` to contain module options and nothing else. If you use the `-M` switch to include the module, like this

```
perl -MO=Deparse -MSwitch -E'switch (1) { }'
```

then the result is this

```
use Switch;
S_W_I_T_C_H: while (1) {
    local $_S_W_I_T_C_H;
    &Switch::switch(1);
}
continue {
    last;
}
-e syntax OK
```

which is different in that neither a compile time nor a run time error is raised.

---

**Update**

The problem seems to be an issue with the [`Filter::Util::Call`](https://metacpan.org/module/Filter::Util::Call) module, on which `Switch` is based. The problem is that the text that this module passes to source filters begins only on the line *following* the `use Switch` statement. Anything after it on the same line is processed directly by the perl parser as normal.

That means that, in your second case, perl is seeing the (unmodified) program `switch (1) {}` while `Switch` has nothing to do as there is no code at all after this line to be filtered.

I think this is highly likely to be an inherent part of perl, and there is no way to intercept the source stream in the mid-line. But it's a non-critical bug and, now that you know the cause, you should be able to work around it easily.

Comment: isn't that the standard behaviour for pragmas to start affecting the line after they are `use`d? Think about something like the well known [Klingon sublanguage](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::tlhInganHol::yIghun#Introduction) (or translation).

Comment: @PatrickJ.S.: Not that I'd heard, but you may well be right. It's a convenient slot to leave something untouched by the pragma but executed after it comes into affect. I can't see that something like that would be documented.

Comment: Yeah, i had remembered it wrong, it only applied to source filter modules that were dependent on `Filter::Util::Call`, like you said.